# Push Android library from GitHub to Android Arsenal

Tags: android, github, repository, jitpack

I've developed an **Android library and successfully uploaded to GitHub**.

Here is my GitHub library repo : https://github.com/sangeethnandakumar/TestTube

I'm using **JITPACK PACKAGE repository** to build the dependency. It works like anything and I deployed around 13 releases (v2.5.3 is the last release).

Here are my Jitpack releases : https://jitpack.io/#sangeethnandakumar/TestTube

I wan't to make this library **available via Android Arsenal**. I have an account on Android arsenal linked with GitHub. I need to set search tags and description for my library at Android Arsenal.

Link to Android arsenal : https://android-arsenal.com

What can be the **steps to do that**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same question once.
There is no as such procedure for that. You have to suggest your project on their website and then after a couple of days, they approve it and it is listed on the website. Go to this url

[Android Arsenal Suggestion Url](https://android-arsenal.com/contact)

They don't mail you or send any confirmation aboout the listing of your project. You will have to keep checking everyday the homepage of the andorid arsenal. That is where they list the latest libraries..

Comment: That's it. Thanks friend